# Add separator and text after numeric scalebar in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, scale-bar

In the numeric scalebar in QGIS 3 is it possible to add a thousands seperator of ',' and also some text after the value?

[image]

This should be "1:500,000 at B0" for example.

I have tried Display and Font options but can't find anything to format the value as numerical with a thousands seperator or add a suffix text.

Comment: I think this isn't possible, look at this issue https://issues.qgis.org/issues/13281

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may achieve what you want by using HTML-frame in the Layout.

In the Layout add a HTML-frame [image], choose 'Source' as HTML-source and add a similar code like this

```
[%'Scale 1:'  || format_number(map_get(item_variables('atlas_map'), 'map_scale'),0) || ' at B0'%]
```

[image]

Change **atlas_map** to the name (id) of your map.
[image]

If you need the comma as separator, this may be the solution (works on my computer set up for Norway):

```
'Scale 1:'  || regexp_replace(format_number(map_get(item_variables('atlas_map'), 'map_scale'),0),'\\D',',') || ' at B0'
```

[image]

Read more about regexp_replace: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php

You may use additional HTML style- or CSS-code to change the appearance further.

Comment: Thanks -that didn't work for me but based on your idea I tried the following {'1:'+format_number((map_get(item_variables('Main'),'map_scale')),0)+' at B0'} and it works.